# How can I add the Microsoft Edge browser to a team city agent that's using a Linux OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teamcity, microsoft-edge, testcafe

I’m in a situation where I’ve uploaded some testcafe UI scripts to teamcity for regression testing, and I’m required to have these scripts run in the Microsoft Edge browser. TeamCity however, is running these scripts on agents that are using a Linux/Ubuntu operating system. On top of that, these agents don’t seem to have Microsoft Edge installed on them, only chrome. I myself am working from a windows computer.

Testcafe’s documentation states that we can add new custom browsers to run scripts in if we edit the browser setting to point to the executable file of that browser. In an attempt to implement this, I downloaded the zip file for Linux’s edge installation, unzipped the files, and realized I didn’t recognize any “.exe” equivalent files like there are for windows applications.

[img of testcafe documentation showing how to point to local browser location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCWpH.png)

[(Source: Browsers | Intermediate Guides | Guides (testcafe.io))](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402828/guides/intermediate-guides/browsers)

So… my question to you all is, is there an executable file for a Linux version of Microsoft edge that I can point the browser settings to so that the teamCity agent will recognize the edge browser? If not, are there any other possible solutions for me to do this? I was also thinking about submitting a ticket to have Microsoft Edge installed on the teamCity agents, instead of trying to point to the unzipped Linux Edge files in my current branch for the team city agent to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edge is available from Microsoft, specifically in deb & rpm format as a quick `Microsoft edge Linux download` search would show. Using the tools available should install it correctly.

Linux does not have files with `.exe`, they have permissions set as to whether they are executable.

Before you do anything, you are probably better installing Linux into a vm and at least attempt to use it & understand how it & other *nix variants work.

The question is though, why you are limiting yourself to only that browser?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post. To answer your question, it seems to be a business requirement. Since our users are using our application in the Microsoft edge browser, we'd like to run our automated regression testing in the same browser.